# Iterating in numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, for-loop

I have a problem with iterating through my numpy array. I have two functions (f and g) and the Timestamp for the x-axis. First, I determined the interception of f and g. Then I wanted to counter how many times the interception happens, while the **values** of my function f are greater than 0.
I got the following error after running the code. (Also I tried f.all() ):

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
>   Use a.any() or a.all()

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv("Sensor2.csv", delimiter=";", parse_dates=True)

df.drop('x', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('y', axis=1, inplace=True)

df["100MA"] = pd.rolling_mean(df["z"], 100, min_periods=1)
df["200MA"] = pd.rolling_mean(df["z"], 200, min_periods=1)


x = np.array(df['Timestamp'])
f = np.array(df['100MA'])
g = np.array(df['200MA'])


index = np.argwhere((np.diff(np.sign(f - g)) != 0)).reshape(-1).astype(int)


counter = 0

for i in np.nditer(index):
    if f > 0:
        counter = counter +1
        print counter
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The last iteration doesn't make sense.  Also don't use `nditer`.  Iterate directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ValueError` is being thrown by the line `if f > 0:`. You have `f` as an array of numbers, and you're asking where it is positive: `f > 0` gives you an array of boolean values.  The `if` statement expects a boolean expression, but you can't coerce the boolean array to a single boolean value.

As the exception message states, to go with the code you have, you need to change `f > 0` to `(f > 0).any()` or `(f > 0).all()`.

Your question makes it sound like what you're trying to do is count the number of times that `index` is `True`, where `f` is positive at the same location (that is, what you actually meant was `if f[i+1] > 0:`).  If this is the case, you can try:

```
index = np.diff(np.sign(f - g)) != 0
counter = (f[1:][index] > 0).sum()
```

I'll point out the off-by-one indexing here (`f[i+1]` and `f[1:]`), which is to correct for [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) making `index` one item smaller than `f`.